# No mostrar registros repetidos, llaves foraneas

Tags: php, laravel, sql-server

les cuento mi inquietud, resulta que tengo un sistema en el cual tengo que hacer un pequeño formulario en el cual el usuario selecciona una orden de manofactura (eso es lo de menos), después de esto le mostrara un formulario con algunas preguntas y sus respectivas respuestas, cada pregunta puede tener 3 respuestas,4,5,etc. no depende de mi, mi problema es que tengo una tabla llamada categorías que en teoría son los títulos de las preguntas, otra tabla en mi BD llamada puntuadores que en teoría son mis respuestas a las preguntas, tengo una llave foránea aquí la cual es la de categorías, básicamente ya tengo toda la funcionalidad del sistema mi inconveniente es que por cada respuesta me muestra el titulo de la pregunta y yo solo quiero que me muestre una sola vez el titulo, quizás sea una cuestión sencilla pero no encuentro respuesta, ya intente de muchas formas y no encuentro la manera, les dejo capturas de lo que tengo y una parte de mi código.

> Este es el resultado que obtengo pero solo quiero que la columna categoria se repita 1 vez por todas sus respuestas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Esta es mi consulta SQL

```
$form = DB::select("SELECT c.IDCATEGORIA,c.CATEGORIA,p.IDPUNTUADOR,p.NOMBRE,p.DESCRIPCION,p.PUNTOS
from categorias as c 
join puntuadores as p on c.IDCATEGORIA = p.IDCATEGORIA
");
```

> Esta es mi vista en la que muestro la información como vieron en la imagen

```
    @foreach($opndesc as $opndesc)
    <input type="hidden" id="opndesc" name="opndesc" value="{{$opndesc->OPNDESC}}">
    <h4 class="m-t-0 header-title">{{$opndesc->OPN}} | {{$opndesc->OPNDESC}}</h4>
@endforeach
    @foreach($rtgopn as $rtgopn)
    <input type="hidden" id="rtgopn" name="rtgopn" value="{{$rtgopn->IDRTG}}">
    @endforeach

    @foreach($opn as $opn)
    <input type="hidden" id="opn" name="opn" value="{{$opn->OPN}}">
    @endforeach
    <thead>
<tr>
<th>CATEGORIA</th>
<th>CRITERIO</th>
<th>PUNTOS</th>
<th>SELECCION</th>

</tr>
</thead>

    @foreach($form as $form)

<td><b>   {{$form->IDCATEGORIA}} . {{$form->CATEGORIA}}</b></td>
        <td>
{{$form->DESCRIPCION}}
</td>
<td>
{{$form->PUNTOS}}
</td>
<td><div class="row">

                                                <input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" id="selection" value="{{$form->IDPUNTUADOR}}">    
                                            </div></td>
</tr>


@endforeach
```

Comment: Para agrupar tus filas simplemente lo haría con un `th rowspan`, modificando un poco tu foreach (quizas por un for para identificar el numero de columnas y filas ha incorporar), tengo la duda si en el código que colocaste esta completo por ello no lo modifique

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Mostrar solo 1 vez la llave foranea](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247277/mostrar-solo-1-vez-la-llave-foranea)

Comment: @Esteban cual codigo en donde ya esta mi foreach?, en ese esta parte de la tabla pero lo que coloque es la informacion que se muestra en la imagen.