# Mostrar solo 1 vez la llave foranea

Tags: sql-server

mi problema es el siguiente, tengo 2 tablas una llamada CATEGORIAS y la otra llamada PUNTUADORES, basicamente la primera es como si fueran mis preguntas y la segunda como si fuesen las respuestas (hablando de un pequeño sistema de encuestas), la cuestion es que tengo una llave foranea de CATEGORIAS a PUNTUADORES, lo que necesito es que al hacer mi consulta no se repitan los valores de CATEGORIAS, que solo se muestren una vez.

> Esta es mi consulta

```
select c.CATEGORIA,p.IDPUNTUADOR,p.NOMBRE,p.DESCRIPCION,p.PUNTOS
from categorias as c 
join puntuadores as p on c.IDCATEGORIA = p.IDCATEGORIA
```

> Este es mi resultado, en el cual quiero que la columna marcada se muestre 1 sola vez y no tantas.
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> Lo que me necesito obtener es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo que los demas campos despues de CATEGORIA, no los quiero asi concatenados, sino uno su por celda, pero solo 1 vez la CATEGORIA y no tantas como en la anterior.

> Este es el resultado que tengo en este momento, la primer columna es la que no quiero que se repita, solo que se muestre 1 vez.
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Estás trabajando con consultas SQL directamente, o estás trabajando con Eloquent?

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres, pero no se puede. La resultados se muestran por filas, y si quieres que en una de ellas se muestre la categoría, se tiene que mostrar en todas.

Comment: Estás buscando una solución que se debe aplicar en el front-end, no en la consulta.

Comment: @LuisCazares y me podrias indicar como deberia ser eso, esque enserio ya intente de muchas formas pero el foreach en Laravel me lo repite.

Comment: @MarcialCahuayaTarqui estoy con consultas directamente.

Comment: @MikelFerreiro y sabes alguna alternativa que podría utilizar?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que tratas de hacer, pero tal vez las with function te puedan ayudar.

Comment: @MarcialCahuayaTarqui edite mi pregunta, espero se entienda un poco mas lo que busco.

Comment: ¿Que lenguaje de programación estás utilizando?, por que que puedo observar en la sección `Lo que me necesito obtener es esto:` asumo que se guarda la información en una sola fila y no en muchas, luego las procesa con split.

Comment: @MarcialCahuayaTarqui utilizo Laravel, esa solución o que puse de lo que necesito, solo es una referencia, si lo estaba haciendo asi pero split no me funciono y lo intente con implode y tampoco, no se con cual mas utilizarlo, o no se que otra solución exista, Laravel me dice que split no esta definida como función.

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr lo que quieres, puedes valerte de la función analítica [`LAG`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-gt/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2012) (disponible a partir de SQL Server 2012).  Con esta función, puedes *ver* el valor de cualquiera de las filas anteriores, en este caso, vamos a comparar el valor de la categoría de la fila actual con la categoría de la fila anterior, si es diferente, devolvemos la categoría, y si es igual, devolvemos una cadena vacía. Con esto, logramos el *efecto* de *imprimir* cada categoría una sola vez.

Suena más complicado de lo que es:

```
with
Categorias as (
          select 1 idCategoria, 'Coordinación' Categoria
union all select 2, 'Precisión'
union all select 3, 'Esfuerzo'
)
,
Puntuadores as (
          select  5 idPuntuador, 1 idCategoria, 'Muy leve' Nombre, 'Descripcion 5' Descripcion, 2 Puntos
union all select  6, 1, 'Leve',         'Descripcion 6',   7
union all select  7, 1, 'Promedio',     'Descripcion 7',  13
union all select  8, 1, 'Considerable', 'Descripcion 8',  18
union all select  9, 1, 'Extremo',      'Descripcion 9',  25
union all select 10, 2, 'Suelto',       'Descripcion 10',  8
union all select 11, 2, 'Cerca',        'Descripcion 11', 10
union all select 12, 2, 'Apretado',     'Descripcion 12', 16
union all select 13, 2, 'Exacto',       'Descripcion 13', 22
union all select 14, 3, 'Poco o leve',  'Descripcion 14',  2
union all select 15, 3, 'Promedio',     'Descripcion 15',  4
union all select 16, 3, 'Apreciable',   'Descripcion 16',  6
)
select   case 
           when c.Categoria = coalesce(lag(c.Categoria) over (order by c.Categoria, p.idPuntuador), 'n/a') then ''
           else c.Categoria
         end Categoria
       , p.idPuntuador
       , p.Nombre
       , p.Descripcion
       , p.Puntos
  from Categorias as c
       inner join Puntuadores p on p.idCategoria = c.idCategoria
 order by c.Categoria, p.idPuntuador
```

Lo cual produce el siguiente resultado:

```
Categoria    idPuntuador Nombre       Descripcion    Puntos
------------ ----------- ------------ -------------- -----------
Coordinación 5           Muy leve     Descripcion 5  2
             6           Leve         Descripcion 6  7
             7           Promedio     Descripcion 7  13
             8           Considerable Descripcion 8  18
             9           Extremo      Descripcion 9  25
Esfuerzo     14          Poco o leve  Descripcion 14 2
             15          Promedio     Descripcion 15 4
             16          Apreciable   Descripcion 16 6
Precisión    10          Suelto       Descripcion 10 8
             11          Cerca        Descripcion 11 10
             12          Apretado     Descripcion 12 16
             13          Exacto       Descripcion 13 22

(12 rows affected)
```

En detalle:

- `lag(c.Categoria) over (order by c.Categoria, p.idPuntuador)` nos devuelve el valor de la columna `Categoría` en la fila anterior, ordenada por `c.Categoría` e `idPuntuador`
- coalesce(), si el valor de la fila anterior es null (cosa que pasa en la primera fila, pues no hay fila anterior), nos devuelve `'n/a'`. Si no es null, nos devuelve el valor de la columna en la fila anterior.
- comparamos este valor con el valor de `c.Categoria` en la fila actual. Si es igual, devolvemos `''`. Si no es igual, devolvemos `c.Categoria`

Comment: gracias, probare lo que me mencionas, puede funcionar aunque siendo sinceros, me parece algo complicado.

Comment: ¿Complicado? ¿en qué sentido complicado?

Answer (score 0):

Es importante entender que cada fila es una entidad independiente de la otra. Por lo tanto, no se puede eliminar un valor de la fila y esperar que se asocie con otra.

Para realizar lo que deseas, necesitas ir al lugar en el que se mostrará al usuario final.

- En un reporte, por lo general se definen grupos y cada grupo tendrá
  un cabecero donde aparecerá el dato que no quieres que se repita.
- En una aplicación, por lo general mostrarás el campo repetido en un
  campo de texto, combo, etiqueta o cualquier objeto para valores
  escalares, mientras que los datos que varían pueden ir en un grid o
  en un objeto que cambie su valor dependiendo de el valor
  seleccionado, en este caso, para el campo Categoría.